# How did the workflow I created in SPD get customized using infopath when I do not have infopath?

Tags: 2013

I have tried to publish my workflow in SPD and am getting a message that tells me the form was customized by InfoPath and is no longer compatible with this workflow due to field changes. I am confused as I don't have InfoPath loaded on any computer on the network. What do I do????

Answer (score 0):

If there is any InfoPath form, you can delete it in List/Library Settings -> General Settings -> Form Settings.